# Find out about links

Tags: macos, terminal, symlink

I have a few links set up.  I can do `ls -l` and get full information about them.

For example:

Me-Machine:Links me$ ls -l ~/Links

```
total 8

lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff  64 26 Jul 23:20 jenkins_tc -> /Users/me/developer/buildproj/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin
```

I only want to see the link,

```
jenkins_tc -> /Users/me/developer/buildproj/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin
```

and not the rest of the stuff.

What would be the command for this?

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
    stat -f "%N%SY" symbolicLinkName
```

will produce the output:

```
    symbolicLinkName -> linkedFileName
```

(-f is the "format" option for "stat".  The %N in the format is the filename of symbolic link and the %SY is the way to print out the name of the file it points to with the string " -> " before it. (The S usually means to print the field as a string but it has the special meaning for "Y", the name of the file pointed to, which adds the arrow before the file name.)